# Combining multiple rows a single row in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

So I'm working on a simple IN/OUT board system to keep track of who enters and leaves and grabs a picture of them.

I have each IN/OUT going to an access table.

**access**

| id | user_id | datetime | direction | image |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 5/6/2021 16:04 | In | 1-1621019890.png |
| 5 | 1 | 5/8/2021 13:25 | Out | 1-1621019891.png |
| 9 | 1 | 5/10/2021 16:14 | In | 1-1621019892.png |
| 12 | 1 | 5/11/2021 13:58 | Out | 1-1621019893.png |
| 15 | 1 | 5/11/2021 14:02 | In | 1-1621019894.png |
| 22 | 1 | 5/11/2021 14:31 | Out | 1-1621019895.png |
| 25 | 1 | 5/11/2021 14:32 | In | 1-1621019896.png |
| 26 | 1 | 5/11/2021 14:34 | Out | 1-1621019897.png |
| 28 | 1 | 5/11/2021 15:02 | In | 1-1621019898.png |
| 29 | 1 | 5/11/2021 15:04 | Out | 1-1621019899.png |
| 32 | 1 | 5/11/2021 15:04 | In | 1-1621019880.png |
| 33 | 1 | 5/11/2021 18:09 | Out | 1-1621019870.png |
| 34 | 1 | 5/11/2021 19:05 | In | 1-1621019860.png |
| 35 | 1 | 5/14/2021 19:16 | Out | 1-1621019808.png |
| 38 | 1 | 5/14/2021 19:18 | In | 1-1621019888.png |
| 39 | 1 | 5/14/2021 19:19 | Out | 1-1621019967.png |

I'm trying to locate a SQL query that will output something similar to this:

| User_id | In | in-image | Out | out-image | Total Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/6/2021 16:04 | 1-1621019890.png | 5/8/2021 13:25 | 1-1621019891.png |  |
| 1 | 5/10/2021 16:14 | 1-1621019892.png | 5/11/2021 13:58 | 1-1621019893.png |  |
| 1 | 5/11/2021 14:02 | 1-1621019894.png | 5/11/2021 14:31 | 1-1621019895.png |  |
| 1 | 5/11/2021 14:32 | 1-1621019896.png | 5/11/2021 14:34 | 1-1621019897.png |  |
| 1 | 5/11/2021 15:02 | 1-1621019898.png | 5/11/2021 15:04 | 1-1621019899.png |  |
| 1 | 5/11/2021 15:04 | 1-1621019880.png | 5/11/2021 18:09 | 1-1621019870.png |  |
| 1 | 5/11/2021 19:05 | 1-1621019860.png | 5/14/2021 19:16 | 1-1621019808.png |  |
| 1 | 5/14/2021 19:18 | 1-1621019888.png | 5/14/2021 19:19 | 1-1621019967.png |  |

It would be great if I could also get it to calculate the total time in but worst case I can do that in PHP.

From doing a lot of searching it would appear that I would need to setup a PIVOT in my MySQL query but not seeing how to do that with multiple columns.

Comment: how do you associate/group a particular in and out row? In real data would the user_id be different?

Comment: The above is just where I did a SELECT * FROM access WHERE user_id=1  so I can see all in/outs for that particular user.  But in the actual DB you would have multiple people going in and out.   ----    I have I guess you're right maybe I need a group table with 3 columns     ID    |    in_id     |   out_id        Then I can just do a join to link them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David784 for the direction.

I ended up creating a new table called accessgroups which just has 2 columns in_id and out_id.  This will allow me to group together 2 access entries.  I can then use that to do a SQL join to get the output exactly how I'd like.

```
SELECT access.user_id,access.datetime as 'IN',access.image as 'IN_IMAGE',(SELECT datetime from access WHERE id = accessgroup.out_id) as 'OUT',(SELECT image from access WHERE id = accessgroup.out_id) as 'OUT_IMAGE' 
FROM `access` 
INNER JOIN accessgroup 
ON access.id = accessgroup.in_id 
WHERE direction = 1
```

Now I just have to modify my webapp to create that row in accessgroups when you sign in and update it with the signout id.  And I'll just use PHP to calculate the difference in IN/OUT times.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your data are regular (no missihng Out row for an In row)

```
select user_id, 
   max(case when direction='In' then datetime end) in,
   max(case when direction='In' then image end) in_image,
   max(case when direction='Out' then datetime end) out,
   max(case when direction='Out' then image end)    out_image
from (select *,
         row_number() over(partition by user_id, direction order by datetime) rn
      from yourtable) t
group by user_id, rn
```